# How to view different profile of an account when a user click on some username in PHP?

Tags: php

I need a help, I'm trying to develop social network where a user can post something and other users can comment on that post, and every user must have his profile (include his names, username, DOB, etc..), when a user click on other users name he must be redirected to the profile of user who he clicked on like other social network (Facebook, Twitter, ...). But the problem is when I try to link, it gives me only the profile of the current user (who is signed in), for example when I'm signed in and click on my name it will give me my profile, but when when  I click on other username different to mine it will still give me my profile. Any help how I can figure out this issue? Thanks

I have tried searching allover the internet but didn't find the solution I want

These is my code

the query to retrieve user profile

```
public function get_user_by_id(){
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $this->db->bind(":id", $_SESSION['id']);
    $row = $this->db->single();
    return $row;
}
```

some code of link to user profile

```
<div class="publish">
    <a href="<?=URLROOT.'/users/profile/'.$post- 
    >first_name.'_'.$post->last_name;?>"><img id="user-img" src="<?=URLROOT;?>/img/avatar.png" /></a>&nbsp;<span><?=$post->first_name;?><?=$post->last_name;?></span>
</div>
```

some code of user profile

```
<tr>
    <td class="font-weight-bold">First Name</td>
    <td><?=$data['get_user']->first_name;?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="font-weight-bold">Last Name</td>
    <td><?=$data['get_user']->last_name;?></td>
</tr>
```

I expected when I click on other username to redirect to their profile but it still redirect to my profile (it means the profile of user who is signed in)

Answer (score 0):

You could start by not making your functions session depended:

```
public function get_user_by_id($userId) {
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $this->db->bind(":id", $userId);
    return $this->db->single();
}
```

This would work for the current user like this:

```
$currentUser = get_user_by_id($_SESSION['id']);
```

But it can also be used for any other user for which the `id` is known.

The page on which you present something about a user, like the profile page, could have an URL like this:

`https://example.com/users/profile?userId=123`

And then in the page itself you use:

```
$userId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "userId", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

to get the user id. Then you can use the function above to retrieve information about the user. Notice that the user id could be invalid. In that case the function above will probably not return anything. You have to respond to that condition appropriately.

A link to a user's profile would be simpler, if you use the user's id, and work in all situations. However, if you still want to use the user's name to look up the profile you have to use something else than `first_name` and `last_name` because that is *unlikely to always be unique*, as it should be. Here on Stack Overflow they use a "Display name", and it has to be unique.

If you use something like a display name you have to create a new function to look up a user by display name:

```
public function get_user_by_display_name($displayName) {
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE displayName = :displayName");
    $this->db->bind(":displayName", $displayName);
    return $this->db->single();
}
```

Comment: It still gives me the same profile of signed user, I don't know what is wrong

Comment: @ErickyVand I've given you as many hints as I could. There's just not enough information in your question to solve any remaining problems. You could ask a new question, after reading: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)